# Concatenating Column Values into a Comma-Separated List in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the T-SQL syntax to format my output so that the column values appear as a string, separated by commas?

For example, my table Rating have the following:

| MbrID | Grade | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12,13 |
| 1 | B | 10,15 |
| 1 | C | 7,3 |

How do I get the output as

| MbrID | FinalRating |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A12,A13,B10,B15,C7,C3 |

Comment: Why replace denormalised data with even worse denormalised data? Now not only does a single value contain delimited data, but each delimited data item represents *two* values (that of `Grade` and `Rating`). Why not fix your design and normalise it?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `string_agg()` in concert with a little `string manipulation` within a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8523b0a531257cf758e1d99d143a3674)**

```
Select MbrID
      ,NewValue = string_agg(V,',')
from  YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values (Grade + replace(rating,',',','+Grade) ) )B(V)
Group By MbrID
```

**Results**

```
MbrID   NewValue
1       A12,A13,B10,B15,C7,C3
```

**Update: 2016 approach**

```
;with cte as (
Select A.MbrID
      ,B.V
from  YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values (Grade + replace(rating,',',','+Grade) ) )B(V)
)
Select MbrID
      ,FinalRating  = stuff((Select ',' +V From CTE  Where [MbrID]=A.[MbrID] For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte A
Group By MbrID
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my sql server is 2016 and string_agg is not supported.

Comment: @Robin See update for a 2016 version using the STUFF/XML approach